# What is the effect of Updating NuGet Package Manager on Existing Projects?

Tags: nuget

I am working on VS2012 and have issue with installing Twilio Package via NuGet. It asks me to update NuGet Package Manager. I am concerned if updating NuGet Package Manager have effect on all the projects that are running without any issue. What are the effects of Package Manager Updates on existing projects or solution.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from the Python world, I will attempt to see if I can help you here. Is the concern that a specific package will no longer be available to you if you do a global update on your NuGet package manager?

Is it possible then for you to install a specific NuGet version in a virtual machine encapsulating the project where you want to run with the [Twilio package](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp)?

Otherwise, assuming all of the packages you use are regularly maintained, I'm not sure how an update to a package manager would affect them.